# Conditional probability of making claim by insurance policyholder

Tags: probability-theory

In any given year,a male automobile insurance  policyholder make a claim with probability $p_m$ and a female automobile insurance policy holder will make a claim with a probability $p_f$ where $p_f \not= p_m$.

The fraction of the automobile insurance policyholders that are male is $\alpha, 0 < \alpha < 1. $ A automobile insurance policyholder is randomly chosen.

If $A_i$ denotes the event this automobile insurance policyholder will make a claim in year *i* , show that $$ P(A_2|A_1) > P(A_1)$$

Give an intuitive explanation of why this preceding inequality is true.

**My answer:**

$P(A_1)$ denotes the event this randomly chosen automobile insurance policyholder will make a claim in first year = $\alpha \times p_m + (1-\alpha) \times  p_f.$

$P(A_2)$ denotes the event this randomly chosen automobile insurance policyholder will make a claim in second year = $ \alpha \times p_m + (1-\alpha) \times p_f. $

$P(A_2|A_1)$ denotes the event this randomly chosen automobile insurance policyholder will make a claim in the second year given that he/she already made a claim in the first year = $\frac{\alpha \times (p_m)^2 + (1-\alpha) \times (p_f)^2 }{\alpha \times p_m + (1-\alpha)\times p_f}$ which is greater than $P(A_1)$

Comment: What's your question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your situation.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.